# Sublime Text 2 Zen Coding CSS Abbreviation

Tags: css, sublimetext, emmet

I'm having some problems with Zen Coding CSS in Sublime Text 2. I've installed Zen Coding on Sublime Text 2 via Package Control and I'm trying to use css abbreviations.

If I write "h" + Tab in a .html file, between () I get a "height: ;" as I was expected but if I do the same thing in a .css file I get "h1" which is not what I expected from Zen Coding.

The same thing happens with all CSS abbreviations. W + TAB, BG + TAB, none of those work properly.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 uses TextMate snippets, so you could use this :
http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=TextMate.Zen.CSS.1.3.1.zip

Just extract the `.tmbundle` file and move it to your packages folder.

Comment: While it's true ST2 supports TM snippets, this advice would not work.  ST2 doesn't support TM commands or actions.  His question has to do with a bug in the ZenCoding plugin.

Comment: Correct, but as far as I can see he is only looking for the snippets. I have my sublime text set up with this snippets and it behaves the way he wants to.